# Unable to access jarfile when running Docker image

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot

I am novice to Spring Boot Microservices and Docker.

The dockerfile in microservice project:

[image: dockerfile]

docker build:

[image: docker build]

docker images:

[image: docker images]

when running the image, there is an error: Unable to access jarfile register_server.jar

[image: error]

Cheers,
Sean

Comment: I don't use docker on `windows` but I would recommend setting the `WORKDIR` so that we can ensure that `register-server.jar` is saved at the place we want it to be and `ENTRYPOINT` is executing the .jar file from where it is supposed to be. Let me know if this helps

Comment: see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/workdir for more information

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify either the absolute target path or set the `WORKDIR`

#### Dockerfile Reference - Add

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add

The `<dest>` is an absolute path, or a path relative to `WORKDIR`, into which the source will be copied inside the destination container. For example:

```
ADD test relativeDir/          # adds "test" to `WORKDIR`/relativeDir/
ADD test /absoluteDir/         # adds "test" to /absoluteDir/
```