# How to run shell scripts along with java applications using docker?

Tags: java, shell, docker, dockerfile

Following is my Dockerfile , i am copying a folder and two java jar files onto the image and the intention was to execute the script file which is inside the copied directory followed by executing the two java applications .

```
FROM openjdk:latest
COPY ./mycluster /dir/latest/
COPY ./app1.jar /dir/latest/
COPY ./app2.jar /dir/latest/ 
CMD ["sh", "-c", "cd /dir/latest/ ;./local_cluster_startup.sh ./;sleep 5 ;java -jar app2.jar;sleep 5;java -jar app1.jar;"]
```

After building the docker image and running the following command **docker container run tryout:nsdap** the output is

```
sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /dir/latest/
sh: 1: ./local_cluster_startup.sh: not found
Error: Unable to access jarfile app2.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile app1.jar
```

Can anyone please tell me what am doing wrong here ?

I am looking for a minimal docker image that would be able to execute java jars and the shell scripts . Can you please help me out ? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access jarfile when running Docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217402/unable-to-access-jarfile-when-running-docker-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WORKDIR (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) to switch to the directory "/dir/latest".
Then you can run your commands from that directory

```
WORKDIR /dir/latest
CMD ["./local_cluster_startup.sh ;sleep 5 ;java -jar app2.jar;sleep 5;java -jar app1.jar;"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @Devesh Kumar Singh , Now am getting following error docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"./local_cluster_startup.sh /dir/latest/;sleep 5 ;java -jar app1.jar;sleep 5;java -jar app2.jar;\": stat ./local_cluster_startup.sh /dir/latest/;sleep 5 ;java -jar app1.jar;sleep 5;app2.jar;: no such file or directory": unknown.
Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Try splltting your command and run them as a list (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

Comment: but i am still facing the same issue CMD ["sh","-c","./local_cluster_startup.sh /dir/latest/ && sleep 5 && java -jar app1.jar && sleep 5 && java -jar app2.jar"]  , i used && to split the commands. But am still facing the oci runtime failed issue . Can you please let me know your comment ?

Comment: You can create the docker by only creating your dockerfile till WORKDIR line, then try running a sequence of commands you would run in CMD list, by deploying that docker image). I mean split the command like
`
CMD ["./local_cluster_startup.sh","sleep 5","java jar app1.jar","java jar app2.jar"]
`

Comment: Still the same issue , if i separate the commands - container itself is not starting but if i use && container is starting but the actual commands were not being executed

Comment: Try ```RUN /bin/bash```. Also look at the duplicate answer link posted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188180/discussion-between-devesh-kumar-singh-and-mozhi).